# Are VPNS safe over any network?

Tags: vpn

I just want to confirm, are vpns actually safe? An IT technician at my college said 'We don't allow private VPNs in or out of the corporate network as a security precaution. They have a potential to allow an attacker to gain a foothold on a device without triggering an immediate security response or execute a remote attack, completely bypassing the firewall protections.'.

So does this mean vpns are not safe enough?

Comment: Please edit your question and describe/elaborate what you mean by "not safe enough".

Answer (score 1):

VPNs are no more or less safe than any other random network on the internet.

Your IT departments problem is that it effectively isolates your traffic from their network and connects you to another network that they have no control over.

It could potentially mean you are merrily downloading every virus, trojan and a hundred colourful malwares without your IT department being able to protect you. Once you disconnect from the VPN you could essentially unleash all of that upon your college network from the inside without all the boundary protections that they might have in place.

It doesn't make VPNs inherently unsafe, but you are bypassing network firewalls, virus scanning appliances, and general network level site blocking that might be in place.

It's not much different to you going to a cafe, connecting to their unsecured WiFi and then going back to your dorm and connecting to the college network. But it is the college networks prerogative to block VPNs so that they can at least monitor and manage traffic appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

VPN stands for virtual private network, meaning all information regarding sent and revived would not be collected without consent.

Therefore if that's what you're worried about, then it shouldn't be a problem.

However if you're worried that the VPN itself may cause damage to your system through networking, then here's the risk.

Using VPN's bypasses all security features to bring you to one straight path to your own private network. Meaning you won't have protection of per say device antiviruses or firewalls. So anything could be sent to your device without you knowing, yet it's rare to happen.

Campuses and schools tend to turn this off so they can track what you do for their benefit, and I've known through experience. I've used VPN's many times, and it's fair to say it's safe enough to browse anonymously without trackage.

Answer (score 0):

What is “safe”?

You can imagine VPNs as a long LAN cable. Anything that is between client and server does not matter. Not other networks (like the internet) nor any firewalls (they can only block the connection completely).

For example you could have a VPN connection from your mobile phone to your home network. When connected, it’s as if you were at home, connected to your WiFi network. This also means that if you run a service on your phone, say a FTP server, a host in your home network could *initiate* a connection to your mobile phone.

That is what your IT department is rightfully worried about: The VPN connection would bypass their corporate firewall rules. Not only outbound rules, but also inbound rules. Only the firewall on the client PC itself remains.

> They have a potential to allow an attacker to gain a foothold on a device without triggering an immediate security response or execute a remote attack, completely bypassing the firewall protections.

It is important to keep in mind that a VPN connection is not a one-way road. If you do not trust a VPN provider, do not connect to it!

In the case of corporate IT, there’s also the problem with industrial espionage and other more benign compliance stuff.